# Bulk remove/convert the .WebP files

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I downloaded some images from a page in a folder, and have all images that finish by `.webp`, say, `toto.jpg.webp`, `titi.png.webp`...

Is there a way in the Window's Command line to bulk remove the `.webp` extension from all the files in the folder?

I tried to `ren *.jpg.webp *.jpg`, but it renamed them in `.jpg.jpg`, I don't like... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that Google's `webp` is not only a file rename, but a real image format that is not compatible with most of the image editors. So, there's not enough to rename, but also to bulk convert such files.

So, I used [XnConevrt](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/#downloads) to bulk convert these files. You just add your folder, select a filter (`.png`, by eg) and then it bulk converts for you all the `.png.webp` to real `.png` files.

Comment: That app is awesome